# PHP move_upload_file failed to open stream: no such file or directory

Tags: php, file, file-upload, upload, move

Im currently working with Jcrop to let users crop an image, after they crop they can upload the image, I want to use php to crop the image and move the file to the correct directory.

This is the tutorial im following: [Tutorial](https://www.script-tutorials.com/html5-image-uploader-with-jcrop/)

In my  i have this input element :

```
<input type="file" name="upload-image" id="upload-image"/>
```

then when the image crop region is selected with Jcrop the user will upload the form. this is the bit of PHP which is not working:

```
 // new unique filename
 $sTempFileName = 'cache/' . md5(time().rand());

 // move uploaded file into cache folder
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload-image']['tmp_name'], "upload/" . $sTempFileName);
```

Then when i upload the form i get these 2 errors.

Warning: move_uploaded_file(../upload/cache/6b769249a48996fd69d527b2412b684e): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

and

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\wamp1\tmp\phpB1A0.tmp' to '../upload/cache/6b769249a48996fd69d527b2412b684e'

I checked a lot of stackoverflow pages already but the all use a folder to upload the image to, but in this tutorial it says it needs to upload the file into the cache folder. That makes me think i don't need to specify a folder to upload to.

Comment: I am using this: enctype="multipart/form-data" on my form

Comment: file extention name is missing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the target directory (../upload/cache/) exists and is writable by the web server.  If you're not certain where the upload/cache directory should be, you can find out by temporarily adding this line right before the call to move_uploaded_file:

```
echo realpath($sTempFileName);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Turns out the $sTempFileName is /cache/randomgeneratedname. I just realised.